# Need to use Session State

Tags: vb.net

VB student that needs some help with a simple two page application that:

1.) Create a sessions counter to show how many registrations are saved each time the "Submit" button is clicked

CODE FOR SESSION COUNT

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
            If Session("key") Is Nothing Then
                Session("key") = 0
            Else
                Session("key") = Session("key") + 1
            End If
            Response.Write(Session("key"))
            LoadData()
        End If
```

2.) Create a "Display" button that will show the above count on a new page when the user clicks it.

CODE TO DISPLAY SECOND PAGE WITH SESSION COUNT

```
Response.Redirect("PageTwo.aspx")
```

But nothing is displaying on the second page when I click the "Display" button. I have tried different ways to adjust my code but it doesn't work.  Instead of me listing all of my changes and attempts I made I just listed my core code and need someone to please show me how I can get this to work.

Comment: Where's any code which responds to a "display button" and attempts to print anything to the page?

Comment: Hi David, I'm trying to figure that part out. I also don't think my session counter is correct

Comment: You need to pass the number to the second page. In the second page, read that number and display it. One way to pass the number is using query string in the URL.

Comment: Han, Instead of me listing all of my changes and attempts I made I just listed my core code and need someone to please show me how I can get this to work.

Comment: Just print out the session on the second page with: Response.Write(Session("key")). Also, under "Not IsPostBack" things don't get executed when there's a postback.

Comment: I updated my code to 'Response.Write("PageTwo.aspx"(Session("key")))' but the second page didn't load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my IF Statement for the "Submit" button to something easier to work with and read.

```
 Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
        'if session is not set then set the session and assign value to 1
        If (Session.Item("numberofRegistration") Is Nothing) Then
            'setting session variable
            Session.Item("numberofRegistration") = 1
        Else
            'taking value from session and incrementing value by 1
            Session.Item("numberofRegistration") = Convert.ToInt32(Session.Item("numberofRegistration").ToString()) + 1
        End If
    End Sub
```

Then for my Display Button, a simple redirect to "PageTwo"

```
Protected Sub DisplayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DisplayButton.Click
        Response.Redirect("PageTwo.aspx")
    End Sub
```

On Page Two I used a Message Label and another IF statement

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'checking if session is set or not
        If (Session.Item("numberofRegistration") Is Nothing) Then
            'if session variable is null then
            'display error message on the lable
            MessageLabel.Text = "Please set the session variable"
        Else
            'display value from session variable on the lable with id=lblMessage
            MessageLabel.Text = String.Format("Total Number of Registrations : {0}", Session.Item("numberofRegistration").ToString())
        End If

    End Sub
```